# App not Responding due to transition

Tags: android, android-transitions

I applied slide transition to move to Activity B through Activity A
Activity A -> Activity B
When i go back to Activity A (By Pressing Back Button)
Activity B -> Activity A
and then again to Activity B
Activity A -> Activity B
App does not respond. What can be possible reason and its solution?
Here is code:-
Activity A:-

```
package com.tester;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActivityOptions;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.transition.Scene;
import android.transition.Slide;
import android.transition.TransitionManager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Anima extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewGroup root_scene;
    Bundle bundle;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.anima);
        root_scene = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root_scene);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.info_image);
        /*final Slide slide = new Slide(Gravity.TOP);
        slide.addTarget(R.id.test_image);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(slide);
        */
        bundle = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle();
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.head);
        Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "roboto.ttf"); 
        tv.setTypeface(type);
        tv.setText("Armed robbers used Pokémon Go to target victims in Missouri");
        iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Anima.this,Second.class);
                startActivity(intent,bundle);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Activity B:-

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActivityOptions;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.transition.Slide;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Second extends AppCompatActivity{
    Bundle bundle;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.another_scene);
      bundle = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle();
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.details);
    Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "robot_light.ttf"); 
    tv2.setTypeface(type);
    tv2.setText("As popular as Pokémon Go has become, that it sends players out into the real world to find Pokémon is creating new, unexpected problems. The O'Fallon, Missouri Police Department reported on Facebook today that armed robbers have used the app to lure victims in and rob them at gunpoint.\nThe police received reports about the robberies and were able to apprehend four suspects in the area. Apparently, the thieves used the app to set up a beacon at a Pokéstop within the game. Using this method, Sergeant Bill Stringer of the OPD told Motherboard that the culprits were able to rob 11 players, all between the ages of 16 and 18, in the St. Louis and St. Charles counties of Missouri.");
    Slide slide =   new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    slide.addTarget(tv2);
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(slide);
}

}
```

Comment: Please share the log

Comment: @sJy App does not crash. it just get hang.

Comment: @sJy Please see the edits

Comment: Do you override onBackPressed()?? Could you post the full activity code??

Comment: @sJy nope doesnt override. btw code updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your **bundle** initialization in Activity **Anima** inside the onClick() method. Try

```
iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bundle = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Anima.this).toBundle();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Anima.this,Second.class);
        startActivity(intent,bundle);
    }
});
```

Comment: The method makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity, Pair<View,String>...) in the type ActivityOptions is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){})

Comment: Thanks dude. working like charm can u tell me the mistake